# call programmatically with picture android

Tags: android, android-intent, call

hey I want to call programmatic-ally and I know its pretty simple

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url));
   startActivity(intent);
```

But I want to display bitmap picture and also name during call.
is there is any way to do that? 
Is there is anything I can put in extras?
thanks